# Where do emails go if a rule sends them to "No mailbox selected"

Tags: mail.app, email, mail-rules

For some reason a Mail rule was unintentionally set to send emails to "No mailbox selected".

This rule has been repaired; however, I do not know where those emails are now!

**Does anyone know if there is a default folder or someplace emails are sent to if a rule sends them to "No mailbox selected"?**

Comment: Nowhere, they died a terrible death :)

Comment: Set up a test: construct a rule to select a test email and move the email to "No mailbox selected. Have a friend send you the email. Then see if you can find it.